# Trying to install Pear on SUSE

Tags: php, pear, suse

I've been trying for hours and googling everywhere to no avail to get Pear installed on a SUSE linux server, I'm stuck at the error:

> ALERT - script tried to disable memory_limit by setting it to a
>   negative value -1 bytes which is not allowed (attacker 'REMOTE_ADDR
>   not set', file '/usr/bin/go-pear.phar', line 1128) ALERT - Include
>   filename ('phar://go-pear.phar/index.php') is an URL that is not
>   allowed (attacker 'REMOTE_ADDR not set', file '/usr/bin/go-pear.phar',
>   line 1236)

I've been installing it with the commands:.

wget http://pear.php.net/go-pear.phar
php go-pear.phar

Any suggestions? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That error is coming from *suhosin*. You could temporarily disable it in `php.ini`.

Comment: Awesome!! I disabled Suhosin by adding the line:

suhosin.simulation = On 

To the php.ini file in /etc/php5/cli/php.ini then ran the two commands again and it worked.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

I found `php -n go-pear.phar` also works w/o requiring root for editing the php.ini